# Disable/Remove Sunday and it related date from calendar

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, calendar

I want to disable/remove Sunday from js calendar and its related dates also.

Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this?

I search from google but all says to hide weekend, I just want to hide only Sunday and its related dates.

[image]

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zXFGN/

Comment: $( "#noSunday" ).datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: noSunday
});

Comment: function noSunday(date){ 
          var day = date.getDay(); 
                      return [(day > 0), '']; 
      };

Comment: yeah! it works please post an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#noSunday" ).datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: noSunday
});

function noSunday(date){ 
     var day = date.getDay(); 
     return [(day > 0), '']; 
};
```